# In C#, Generically get the property value within a List object

Tags: c#, list, object, reflection

I have a Match object structured as,

```
class Match
{
    public string location { get; set; }
    public List<Team> teams { get; set; }
    public Match()
    {
        location = "Wembley";
        teams = new List<Team>();
        teams.Add(new Team("Arsenal"));
        teams.Add(new Team("Burnley"));
    }
}
public class Team
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public Team(string title)
    {
        name = title;
        score = 0;
    }
}
```

I use a  helper class to get the value,

```
public static class Helper
    {
        public static object GetPropertyValue(this object T, string PropName)
        {
            return T.GetType().GetProperty(PropName) == null ? null :  T.GetType().GetProperty(PropName).GetValue(T, null);
        }
    }
```

I am planning to allow the user to set values by typing them in a GUI as "match.team[1].name" for example and then split this to a parameter call such as in this code; this may go down several layers. Here we go down a layer to get a property value from a member of the list,

```
int teamNo = 1;
MessageBox.Show(GetSubProperty(match, "teams", teamNo, "name"));
```

My routine is this,

```
    private string GetSubProperty(object obj, string prop1, int whichItem,  string prop2)
    {
        var o = obj.GetPropertyValue(prop1);
        object subObject = ((List<Team>)o)[whichItem];
        return subObject.GetPropertyValue(prop2).ToString();
    }
```

When getting a property in one of the Team List objects, I have to cast the value to  List before accessing the individual item in the list. I wanted to know how I could do this generically for any object type being sent in. I tried List  and ArrayList and quite a few other variations but am getting an error" Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[quickTest.Classes.Team]' to type  'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]"

Comment: Is it necessary to expose your object layout to the user in this way and expect them to be aware of it ? Why not just have a UI that allows them to just set a team name etc without it being tied to your class layout.

Comment: What UI framework are you using ? If Winforms or WPF then both of those have powerful data binding mechanisms that would be better suited for this sort of object data updates

Comment: Valid points, thanks, but although the back end is in C#, the front end may not be. I can reflect on the model to give the user the data structures, they can then direct that data to other streams.

Comment: See my second comment about data binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IEnumerable. This seems to work:

```
private string GetSubProperty(object obj, string prop1, int whichItem, string prop2)
{
    var o = obj.GetPropertyValue(prop1);

    int count = 0;
    foreach (object subObject in (IEnumerable)o)
    {
        if (whichItem == count++)
        {
            return subObject.GetPropertyValue(prop2).ToString();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Of course, be sure to check that this cast worked. You can make your solution more generic by trying to cast to various things and executing the appropriate code based on the type that o is.